# Добавить пробелы длиной = слову

Tags: c#

Дана строка, содержащая слова, разделенные одиночными
пробелами. Сформировать строку, в которой количество пробелов перед
каждым словом будет равно его длине.
Какой использовать алгоритм действий? Уже все перепробовал, ничего на ум не приходит больше... Пытался и через массивы, и через `Padleft()`. Уже не знаю что придумать.

Answer (score 1):

Если строка небольшая, то

```
var str = "longstring  one two   three"
    .Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(x=>new string(' ', x.Length) + x)
    .Aggregate((x,y)=>x+y);
    
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Если большая, то надо StringBuilder использовать.

Comment: Это точно c#? Не работает никак. У меня приложение WindowsForms

Comment: это точно C#, что конкретно у вас не работает?

Comment: `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` в этой строке показывает ошибку

Comment: версия фреймворка какая? `using System;` добавили?

Comment: @НиколайБалыков не стоит писать новый софт на базе устаревшего дотнета.